# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4peSC.png)

I am trying to using React Bootstrap but I don't know why this is not working.
Please tell me why I getting this error?

I provided code below in two parts:
Header.js (where I'm using react-bootstrap) and
App.js

MY CODE

Header.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';


const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
      <br />
      <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>

      <br />
      <Navbar bg="light" variant="light">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
      </div>
  )
}


export default Header;
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './MyComponents/Header';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Header></Header>
    </>
  );
} 

export default App;
```

Please help me with as simple as possible solution, I am new to React

Comment: I don't see a problem in your code. Can you check your configurations?

Comment: Thankyou Ahsan-J for your comment, Please can you explain what configurations?

Comment: In which file have you used `useRef`? Upload that file here,

Comment: Ankit I provided you my Github repo link https://github.com/birattam005/first-app

Comment: it's still unclear checked out your repo theirs is no problem.

Comment: Jug Patel please check one more time